# Purple Screen on Boot NVIDIA 960 and no acces to recovery mode

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, gpu

So I have a 960 GPU and a 650 GPU, my 650 works pretty well on ubuntu 14, and I've been trying to install my 960 the problem is that even tho I installed the drivers from the official site I can't get it to work, I've done everything in the solutions but still no fix. the things I've done:
- purge all nvidia drivers then re install all
- install different versions of the nvidia drivers
- I followed this solution step by step 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2263316

And worst off all I can't access revocery mode when the Gtx 960 is plugged in. I will hang in Loading initial ramdisk.
I if i edit the grub in boot screen to "nomodeset" with the 960 plugged it wont work.
I can perfectlly use my 650 with any NVIDIA driver I tried for the 960 but
if only if i dont ever plug the 960, like if I try a driver and reboot with the 650 it works, then try it with the 960 and fails, it won't work anymore with the 650. I don't know why.

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say official site, please specify clearly from when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1 : Uninstall every currently installed NVIDIA software.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter your user name and your password - execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo poweroff
```

Step 2 : Unplug the NVIDIA 650 GPU and plugin the NVIDIA 960 GPU.

Step 3 : Install the latest official NVIDIA drivers from the long-lived branch.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter your user name and your password - execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, I did all that you told me except form one thing, I can't really disconnect the 650, because I'm using a external GPU connection for my laptop, so the 650 is integrated in the MB, the external GPU adapter connects to the mPCI, in my laptop. but we made progress because im able to boot the computer now with the 960 connected only problem is that it will detect only the 650 and not the 960, I was running this setup in windows 10 without a problem, The 960 turns on as i boot but the fans stops spinning as soon as Ubuntu loads, and in NVIDIA X SERVER the 960 won't show up.

Comment: @cacosta : Please check in BIOS whether you can disable the 650 adapter ... maybe this makes it possible to use the 960 card. :)

Comment: Update: after much digging I used the lspci -v command and the 960 is not detected, I checked all connectins and the GPU is turn on on boot, any ideas?

Comment: any idea how to do this?

Comment: @cacosta : Please provide me with the output from : lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'

Comment: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 650M] (rev a1)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3972
 Kernel driver in use: nvidia

Comment: @cacosta : Sorry, I am running out of ideas ... if you cannot deactivate the 650 card, it seems to be not possible to use the 960 adapter together with with it at the same time ... :)

Comment: =( Im downloading windows now, never thought linux would fail me, the problem with my BIOS is that is locked and i cannot disable the 650, and i don't know the reason why the 960 won't show up. I will heck with windows if the 960 is detected

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think cl-netbox answer will work for most of the people, but that didn't solved mine due the fact that I'm running 2 NVIDIA cards at the same time and I can't deactivate the integrated one (650M). If someone finds a solution for my special situation it would be AWESOME, currently the only thing i ould made was to install windows and use the 960 in windows.